# How to set HTTP header globally on a HTTPS Load Balancer?

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I'm migrating from Kubernetes to Cloud Run. Currently, Kubernetes Ingress allows me to use Nginx Ingress Controller annotations to set headers globally for all subdmains in a single configuration like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 150m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "1200"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1200"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1200"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-fail-timeout: "1200"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      set $http_origin "${scheme}://${host}";
      if ($http_origin ~* (^https?://([^/]+\.)*(app|staging|dev|beta)(\.example\.com)$)) {
          add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
      }
      more_set_headers "server: hide";
      more_set_headers "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff";
      more_set_headers "Referrer-Policy: strict-origin";
```

I want to achieve a similar routing setup but using the global HTTPS Loadbalancer to route traffic to my Cloud Run deployments. Going through the Google Cloud Loadbalancer docs I've came up with this configuration:

```
defaultService: projects/dev/global/backendServices/hello-default-backend
name: example
routeRules:
- matchRules:
  - prefixMatch: /blue
  priority: 2
  routeAction:
    weightedBackendServices:
    - backendService: projects/dev/global/backendServices/hello-blue-backend
      weight: 100
    urlRewrite:
      hostRewrite: hello-blue-backend
  headerAction:
    responseHeadersToAdd:
    - headerValue: DENY
      headerName: X-Frame-Options
      replace: true
- matchRules:
  - prefixMatch: /green
  priority: 3
  routeAction:
    weightedBackendServices:
    - backendService: projects/dev/global/backendServices/hello-green-backend
      weight: 100
    urlRewrite:
      hostRewrite: hello-green-backend
  headerAction:
    responseHeadersToAdd:
    - headerValue: DENY
      headerName: X-Frame-Options
      replace: true
```

As you can see, in the config above I need to specify the header for each matchRules block. Is there any way to achieve a similar result of what I have in the Nginx Ingress Controller? At least having a global way to define the header.

Comment: `X-Frame-Options` is obsolete. It is recommended to use Content-Security-Policy.

Comment: @AlexD That wasn't my question. This header is just an example. My question is wheather or not I can set them globally on the given Loadbalancer config.